# How to open/display the attribute table from a GDB with Arcpy to help QC previous notebook code steps before moving on to the next steps in script?

Tags: arcpy, jupyter-notebook, pygeoprocessing

Within ArcGIS Pro 3.1, I've created a Jupyter notebook that automates pulling records from an SDE feature class, then filters those based on a Geocode Score. The records above 80 remain in the Warehouse Export feature class. The records that are below 80 are exported to another table.

Then, the results for this batch of failed records are filtered into valid (actual addresses) or invalid (address like "%0%" or address like "%test%") tables. Then the valid table is run through a different geocoder. The process is repeated for the resulting feature class sending the valid failed records through a different geocoder.

Then, passing feature classes are cleaned up by deleting unnecessary fields and adding fields that will help match when appending the data to another SDE table.

Then, the passing features are appended to a test feature class which is a clone of the SDE prod feature class.

In the step between, the test feature class and appending to the prod feature class, I'd like arcpy to open/display the actual tables created in the GDB, so the end user can get a quick visual check of the tables and feature class tables to see if everything looks good before appending to the final SDE production feature class.

I added NumPy Arrays and data frames throughout the code to do quick qc checks while working through the flow, but I'd like to have a nice user interface touch of being able to run the code and when it gets to the step of appending to test table successfully it displays/opens the tables to the users.

I've tried to include bits and pieces that help give some context of the code without pasting the whole code here. And the code is working well. So, that's why I'd like to add this additional detail.

```
inPoints_c = r"X:\Planning\Projects\CDA\2024\Test_Script_Run_Jan_2024.gdb\Permit_C_GeocodeAddresses_2_{}".format(today)

out_permit_c_points= r"X:\Planning\Projects\CDA\2024\Test_Script_Run_Jan_2024.gdb\Permit_C_GeoPassed_2_{}".format(today)

points_c_expression= arcpy.AddFieldDelimiters(arcpy.env.workspace,"Score")+ "> 79"

arcpy.conversion.ExportFeatures(inPoints_c, out_permit_c_points, points_c_expression)

all_c_Points = r"X:\Test_Script_Run_Jan_2024.gdb\Permit_C_GeocodeAddresses_2_{}".format(today)

c_failed_records= r"X:\Test_Script_Run_Jan_2024.gdb\Permit_C_Failed_2_{}".format(today)

fail_c_expression= arcpy.AddFieldDelimiters(arcpy.env.workspace,"Score")+ "< 80" 

arcpy.conversion.ExportTable(all_c_Points, c_failed_records, fail_c_expression)

c_pass = arcpy.da.TableToNumPyArray(r"X:\Test_Script_Run_Jan_2024.gdb\Permit_C_GeoPassed_2_{}".format(today),('USER_USER_Permit_No','USER_USER_Address'))

c_fail = arcpy.da.TableToNumPyArray(r"X:\Test_Script_Run_Jan_2024.gdb\Permit_C_Failed_2_{}".format(today),('USER_USER_Permit_No','USER_USER_Address'))

c_pass_df =pd.DataFrame(c_pass,)
c_fail_df = pd.DataFrame(c_fail,)

print(c_pass_df)
print(c_fail_df)

#set up parameters to add permit text field necessary for appending to PROD FC
Permit_A_Pass=r"X:\Test_Script_Run_Jan_2024.gdb\Warehouse_Export_2_{}".format(today)
Permit_B_Pass=r"X:\Test_Script_Run_Jan_2024.gdb\Permit_B_GeoPassed_2_{}".format(today)
Permit_C_Pass=r"X:\Test_Script_Run_Jan_2024.gdb\Permit_C_GeoPassed_2_{}".format(today)

arcpy.management.AddField(f'{Permit_A_Pass}', fieldName2,"TEXT",
                         field_length=fieldLength)
arcpy.management.AddField(f'{Permit_A_Pass}', fieldName3,"TEXT",
                         field_length=fieldLength)

arcpy.management.AddField(f'{Permit_B_Pass}', fieldName2,"TEXT",
                         field_length=fieldLength)
arcpy.management.AddField(f'{Permit_B_Pass}', fieldName3,"TEXT",
                         field_length=fieldLength)

arcpy.management.AddField(f'{Permit_C_Pass}', fieldName2,"TEXT",
                         field_length=fieldLength)
arcpy.management.AddField(f'{Permit_C_Pass}', fieldName3,"TEXT",
                         field_length=fieldLength)

target = r"X:\Geocode_Inputs.gdb\CAD_DEV_BUILDING_PERMITS_TEST"

arcpy.management.Append([f'{Permit_A_Pass}',f'{Permit_B_Pass}',f'{Permit_C_Pass}'], target, "Test")
```